# How to get and delete files from storage using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I'm building a job search application where a Candidate User can upload a profile of themselves along with 3 (quick, about 30 second) videos based on pre determined questions. For example one of the questions is "1. What makes you stand out over other candidates?". He can video himself answering the question and then upload the video.

The way my system works is, the videos get uploaded to a tmp Disk that I created and into a videos folder, then the files get uploaded to s3.
After this happens I want to delete the files from the tmp folder but I keep getting errors.

Here is the tmp Disk in config/filesystems.php:

```
'tmp' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public'

        ],
```

I think that there might be a bug in my application because I can't delete any files from this location, in fact I can't even get them.

When I try to get a file and die dump it that I know is in storage/videos/ folder like this:

```
dd(Storage::get(storage_path().'/videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4'));
```

When I click on the network tab on the response it says `No response data`.

and if I try to delete a file like this:

```
Storage::delete(storage_path().'/videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4'));
```

I keep getting this error:

```
League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path: videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/highrjobsadminlte/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:389
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check that the file you are trying to delete actually exists at `/storage/videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get file using storage facade

You can specify the disk using the `Storage` facade and then get your desired files. Something like below code may help you:

```
Storage::disk('tmp')->get('videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4')
```

### Delete file using facade

As said in getting file section, you can delete any file or directory after specifying the *disk*.

```
Storage::disk('tmp')->delete('videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4')
```

### Check available directories and files

If you doubt about whether you're in the correct disk or not, you can check the existing directories and files in the target disk using `allDirectories()` or `allFiles()` methods.

```
Storage::disk('tmp')->allDirectories();
Storage::disk('tmp')->allFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default disk used by filesystem is configured in `config/filesystems.php`

```php
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

'disks' => [
//other disks
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
   ],
//...
]
```

However you use a custom disk `tmp` when storing the file and have set it's root to `storage_path()` whereas the default `local` disk has the root path set to `storage_path('app')`

So inorder to delete the file in `tmp` disk you should specify the disk

```php
Storage::disk('tmp')->delete('/videos/1607107892Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4');
```